# $n\in N, n\ge2, a,b,c\in Z$. Prove if $ab\equiv 1(modn)$ then $\forall c \not\equiv 0(modn)$ then $ac\not\equiv 0(modn)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n\in N, n\ge2, a,b,c\in Z$. Prove if $ab\equiv 1(modn)$ then $\forall c \not\equiv 0(modn)$ we have $ac\not\equiv 0(modn)$

So I can see that if $ab\equiv1(modn)$ then ab=1 or ab=n-1. If ab=1 then we're done because a=b=1 and $c\not\equiv0(modn)$

But I don't know about when ab=n-1

Comment: Let $ac\equiv 0\,(\mod\,n)$, then multiply by $b$: $bac\equiv 0\,(\mod\,n)\Rightarrow (ba)c\equiv 0\,(\mod\,n)$, can you take it from there?

Comment: Then $c\equiv 0(modn)$ and that's a contradiction?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin You should consider posting an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ac\equiv 0\,(\bmod n)$, multiply by $b$: $bac\equiv b\cdot0\,(\bmod n)$, then recalling $ab\equiv 1\,(\bmod n)$ we get $c\equiv 0\,(\bmod n)$, hence a contradiction. QED